# Why, when I print in 13x13 mode, am I getting 11.40x11.40?

Tags: printing

I wanna print on a custom paper (13x13 200gm Glossy) with a custom print form in Windows 7. With this configuration, the result is not what I've set. What I'm getting is an 11x11cm, top left aligned picture.
My printer is the **HP LaserJet Pro 200 Color**.

[image: Le Configuration]

Comment: Have you tried setting the margins to 0?

Comment: Also note that many printers are actually incapable of printing on the complete paper area. This is often true for A4 and equivalent sizes, not quite sure how this works out for smaller paper sizes.

Comment: @jcaron it's all on 0.00cm

Comment: @VarandVartanian, it's **not** 0.00cm in your print-screen. You have here a margin of 1cm from every margin (top, bottom, left, right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot indicates you have a specified margin of 1.00cm on all four sides. If you are setting the margins at zero and they are defaulting back to 1.00cm (or to 0.8cm as indicated by your stated 11.4cm² result), it may be that your printer is not capable of printing without a minimum margin of 0.8-1.0cm.